# Suppress stack traces of child processes launched with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

The websockify tool creates a child process for each client. And when terminating the main process it prints stack traces for all children.

```
Process Process-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/websockify/websocket.py", line 930, in top_new_client
    client = self.do_handshake(startsock, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/websockify/websocket.py", line 805, in do_handshake
    ready = select.select([sock], [], [], 3)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/websockify/websocket.py", line 922, in do_SIGTERM
    self.terminate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/websockify/websocket.py", line 895, in terminate
    raise self.Terminate()
```

How to avoid that?

To reproduce:

```
# Install websockify
pip install websockify

# Launch the server
websockify :12345 :1234

# Launch netcat in the other terminal
nc localhost 12345 &

# Kill the main process of websoclify
kill <pid-of-websockify>
```

Sample output of websockify:

```
$ websockify :12345 :1234
WebSocket server settings:
  - Listen on :12345
  - Flash security policy server
  - No SSL/TLS support (no cert file)
  - proxying from :12345 to :1234
127.0.0.1: ignoring empty handshake
In exit
Terminating child 1032
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/websockify/websocket.py", line 930, in top_new_client
    client = self.do_handshake(startsock, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/websockify/websocket.py", line 805, in do_handshake
    ready = select.select([sock], [], [], 3)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/websockify/websocket.py", line 922, in do_SIGTERM
    self.terminate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/websockify/websocket.py", line 895, in terminate
    raise self.Terminate()
websockify.websocket.WebSocketServer.Terminate
```

Comment: Please create a minimal example demonstrating the issue!

Comment: Added test example.